# Slow restore using xp_retore_database / SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, litespeed

I'm using the litespeed extendedSP xp_restore_database to restore an database X in our differents environments,

This SP is fast (~ 10 minutes) an all our environnements, except one. The restore take 45 minutes before its started.

Knowing that our environments are clones, they had the same configuration.

Have you any idea about the performance of this SP ? or any informations that can help ?

Thanks,

Comment: Since restoring databases is functionality tightly integrated with the engine, it's most likely that `xp_restore_database` does little that's more interesting than issuing T-SQL `RESTORE` commands, plus maybe some minor bookkeeping for itself. You ought to be able to trace what it's doing using Profiler and use the usual troubleshooting material for slow `RESTORE` operations beyond whatever it is that LiteSpeed does. At the very least, you should be able to confirm if it's the `RESTORE` itself that is slow, or whatever extra thing LiteSpeed does.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried to trace this restore with "backup_restore_progress_trace" Extended events. I notice that the restore hangs with the trace message = Completed MSDA and trace message = MSDA Processing of size 16383 extents. it repeated these two messages in several events

Comment: Did you have an idea what these two messages mean? Thanks

Comment: Not really. "MSDA" is internal gobbledygook, I'm afraid. 16383 extents = 16383 * 8 pages * 8 KB/page = ~1M of data, that's all I can parse. However, since the event is "completed" it's likely that's *not* where it's hanging, but at whatever comes after that, which your trace isn't including. Try other mechanisms for investigating what "hung" tasks are doing (`sys.dm_exec_sessions join sys.dm_exec_requests cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text`) or perform a more complete trace where you trace individual SQL statements. It may be what comes *after* the restore that takes long.

Comment: Also, try low-hanging fruit like the SQL Server error log (`sp_readerrorlog`) in case you haven't checked that for interesting messages already.

Comment: ok, thank you. In fact, it starts by displaying the two messages " BackupStream () MSDA Processing of size 16384 extents" and "BackupStream () completed MSDA", it repeats these two messages several times, after it begins to decrement gradually the name of the extents until 16 extents and then it return the message "log zeroing is complete" and it start the processing MSTL.

Comment: Oh, then DA = Data and TL = Transaction Log, that seems fairly obvious. I've never had a need for delving into the internals of restoring, however. The basics are 1) allocate space for data files, 2) copy contents of data files, 3) allocate space for transaction log + zero it out, 4) copy transaction log, 5) upgrade storage format/version to current version (if necessary), 6) replay transaction records from transaction log (if any were present in the backup). 5 + 6 are part of bringing the database online (and 6 is skipped under `NORECOVERY`); after this the database is ready for use.

Comment: If it "hangs" or there is noticeable delay between the data copy steps, that suggests that I/O is the problem -- either reading it from the source medium or writing it to the destination. Troubleshooting that is a bit involved, but can be done outside SQL Server with things like `diskspd` and `sqliosim`. If the delay is in creating the files, that may be because your server does not have instant file initialization turned on -- search on that term for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's clear now. I checked for instant file initialization and it's seems enable. I think its the I/O problem because the trace_level indicate "Verbose I/O related information" message when the process hangs.